# Nothing returned in feathersjs before hook sequelize association

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-hook

I've created a before hook in my users service that's meant to include a record from the organizations model.   The relationship between users and organizations is

```
users.belongsToMany(models.organizations,{through: 'users_to_organizations'});
```

The before hook is called attach-orgnaization.js and looks like

```
module.exports = (options = {}) => {
  return async context => {
    const organizations = context.app.services.organizations.Model;
    context.params.sequelize = {
      include: [{model: organizations}]
    };
    return context;
  };
};
```

It's set in users.hooks.js like this

```
....
const attachOrganization = require('../../hooks/attach-organization');
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [authenticate('jwt'), attachOrganization()],
....
```

When I GET `/users?id=1` I get the user back with nothing about the org that the user is associated with in `users_to_organizations`, which happens to be org 3 "test org".

I was expecting to see additional organization related fields in the response.

Instead I see only

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "hello@feathersjs.com",
            "googleId": null,
            "githubId": null,
            "createdAt": "2020-04-29T04:26:49.541Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-04-29T04:26:49.541Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Stepping through the debugger (pycharm) I can see that the code in the hook is executing.

I guess that either sequelize isn't seeing the relationship or feathers is not adding the include to the query.

What might I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue was that I was using the query string to specify the ID.  While that returns the user, it does not seem to cause feather-sequelize to do anything with the include parameter.  Using `/users/1`, as it really should be, returns the organization with the user.

Answer (score 0):

In feathersjs, Get Method has 2 types

1. `Get` : To get a specific data . Ex: `GET /user/:id` (id is the user id)
2. `Find` : To get all data with filters , Ex : `GET /user?name=xyz` (It'll return all the documents with name xyz)

You have attached the `attachOrganization()` in the get method and calling `/users?id=1` which is FIND method.So either call it by `/users/1` id 1 is your `_id` or add the `attachOrganization()` to the hooks of `find` method too